# How to update widget's content through PHPMyAdmin

Tags: wordpress, widget

I have a project in which I am editing an existing wordpress dump file (SQL) and wp-config.php in order to create a new website.

One of the things I do when I edit the dump file is change 3 widgets' content. I put 3 custom html widgets with MyHTMLTitle1/2/3 for titles and MyHTMLContent1/2/3 for content up front, so this is the text in widget_custom_html:

```
a:4:{i:3;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:12:"MyHTMLTitle1";s:7:"content";s:14:"MyHTMLContent1";}i:4;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:12:"MyHTMLTitle2";s:7:"content";s:14:"MyHTMLContent2";}i:5;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:12:"MyHTMLTitle3";s:7:"content";s:14:"MyHTMLContent3";}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}
```

In addition, they are in the footer area. This is the text in sidebars_widgets:

```
a:4:{s:19:"wp_inactive_widgets";a:0:{}s:9:"sidebar-1";a:3:{i:0;s:8:"search-2";i:1;s:14:"recent-posts-2";i:2;s:12:"categories-2";}s:8:"footer-1";a:3:{i:0;s:13:"custom_html-3";i:1;s:13:"custom_html-4";i:2;s:13:"custom_html-5";}s:13:"array_version";i:3;}
```

So, logically, I thought that in order to edit the custom_html's title and content, I just need to replace the title 'MyHTMLTitle1/2/3' with my title and do the same for content. However, when I change the values through phpMyAdmin and go to my website, the footer area (which previously contained 3 widgets) is now empty, and widget_custom_html automatically gets updated to:

```
a:1:{s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}
```

I didn't find any other table that contains details about widgets and so I am lost.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this from Google, the problem was that in addition to the content changes I also needed to change the number of characters in the string. For example, the line `{s:5:"title";s:12:"MyHTMLTitle1";s:7:"content";s:14:"MyHTMLContent1";}` 
should be changed to `{s:5:"title";s:3:"aaa";s:7:"content";s:2:"aa";}`.

Notice that the number before each content changed too, i.e. `"content";s:14` was changed to `"content";s:2:`.